# Symfony2: referring foreign keys in symfony2

Tags: symfony

This is my query to get the desired product and set its values in symfony2

```
$item->setProduct($id)
     ->setQuantity(1)
     ->setTemp($s1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using foreign keys you should use

```
(getReference('YourBundle:EntityName',$id)
```